# Using Bayes' Formula, how to obtain class prior and other components from the data

Tags: bayesian, prior

I am trying to solve the following problem using Bayes' formula 'Given visitors have visited a page, what is the probability they will convert?'

I have a website with which people interact. It has 50 pages, users click on an element on the website and they are redirected to a page. I have collected some information and would like to know which pages are predictors of conversions. I have worked out one example by hand before I write a program to automate it. I have the following information:

Last year, I had 5,000 visitors visiting 'pageA'. Out of those, 1900 were converts (note, people don't convert because of the page, it is not causal relationship). If I use the above information and count the frequencies, such as, total_converts /total_visited_pageA= 1900/5000 = 0.38. This tells me that people who visit pageA, 38% of them will convert.

But I have additional information so I thought I could use Bayes' formula and incorporate prior information. Last year, I had 20,000 visitors. 2,000 of 20,000 visitors converted. I have the following:

P(convert) = 2000/20000 = 0.1 (which is prior info.)

P(visit_pageA | convert) = 1900/2000 = 0.95

P(visit_pageA) = 5000/20000 = 0.40

P(convert | visit_pageA) = [P(visit_pageA | convert) * P(convert)] / P(visit_pageA)

But when I plug in the numbers, they cancel out and it seems that P(convert | visit_pageA) is equal to (total_converts/total_visited_pageA ) (**see the bottom of the post). Am I using the Bayes' in a wrong way? Did I choose the prior correctly? I have never applied Bayes to a real-life situation and I have only looked at medical examples where probabilities are given and conditional probability is calculated.

Bayes' formula worked out:

P(convert | visit_pageA):
= [(1900/2000) * (2000/20000)] / (5000/20000)
= 1900/5000

which is same as (total_converts /total_visited_pageA )

Comment: 5000/20000 does not make 0.4 ...

Comment: Thanks for catching that @Mayeulsgc.